# How do I try out a new bass before buying?

Tags: bass-guitar

I am in the market for a new bass for myself (Schecter Stiletto 5-Studio), and none of the retail music shops (Guitar Center or Sam Ash) carry it because it's not a new model, and of course the selection at those stores is limited. I'm not asking where, *specifically*, I can buy one (although feel free to list any place within 100 miles of Los Angeles if you DO know), but I want to know how I can go about trying a few of them out.

As for why I am confident in that particular bass, I love the price and have experience with similar 4 string models, and have also watched several videos of players demoing the 5 string. I am open to other similar options.

Comment: A long shot, but a wanted ad. may turn up a preloved bass, (you did say it's not a new model). You can then try it out if it's close enough. Or check out small ads and ebay etc. Might even be a better price than from retail.

Comment: You probably know this, but if Schecter is like fender etc, then the model number alone is not enough, since they modify the hardware and electronics etc. from unit to unit. It isn't just about setup. IMO you should not rely on testing one and buying elsewhere: treat every one you play as unique.

Comment: Sometimes stores will special order an item without a commitment to buy on your part because they assume they can sell it to someone else.  Worth asking.

Answer (score 2):

While [Schecter's dealers page](http://www.schecterguitars.com/dealers) doesn't tell you much beyond who is an official Schecter dealer, the company itself might know more. I'd contact them and ask. Failing that, call several of the independent shops and ask them.

If that fails, I'd go online and see if you can get in touch with owners of this bass, or a model like it. Perhaps you can find someone who'll let you try theirs out.

If none of this works, you'll just have to take a chance and order one. I'd stick with reputable instrument dealers like Sweetwater and Elderly, who will at least set the bass up well and help you after the purchase. While I'd never suggest that a new player do this, if you've been playing for a while you'll know what you want in a bass and can at least make an educated decision.

Answer (score 1):

The only way I bother with is to buy second hand for a reasonable price (taking the relevant precautions) locally, from ebay, or from an internet forum, try it at my leisure, and sell on if it's not right for me.

That way, if it's right, I've got it for a good price; if not, I shouldn't (on average) lose too much money when I sell it on.

Trying basses in a shop is almost always a disappointment for me : instruments are usually badly set-up for a start, not to mention the shortcomings of the environment and having someone hovering over you wanting to make a sale.

Another way to go is to find a store that has new stock and a reasonable returns policy.

Answer (score 1):

I wanted to try the Schecter Stiletto as well and ordered one from Zzounds, a four string. They have a 100% return policy. I played it for about two weeks and returned it. I tried different strings on it, but I still didn't care of rate tone, although it was a beautiful and very comfortable bass to play. It was a tough decision, but I got a 100% refund.